Hibernate - passing an entity instance as a parameter value to NativeQuery.setParameter()
We used to pass entity instances as parameter values to Hibernate's NativeQuery.setParameter(). This used to work in Hibernate 3, 4, 5, where Hibernate was internally extracting and using as a JDBC parameter value the Id of corresponding entity instance.
However, this does not work anymore in Hibernate 6, which throws an exception "Could not resolve NativeQuery parameter type" in its JdbcParameterBindingsImpl class.
For example:
Person person = ...;
NativeQuery nativeQuery = session.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM people_table WHERE person_id = :bind_person");
nativeQuery.setParameter("bind_person", person);
return nativeQuery.uniqueResult();

In order to work in Hibernate 6 we had to change the code to:
nativeQuery.setParameter("bind_person", person.getPersonId());

Are we missing something? Could we avoid such code modifications, since the application is big and we would have to investigate each existing setParameter() invocation in order to check whether it is using an entity instance or scalar value?
